# MATLAB. How to remove rows, if any of the values in the row is found in another row?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix as shown in the image. In this matrix if any of the values in one row is found in another row we remove the shorter row. For example row 2 to row 5 all contain 3, therefore I want to keep only row 5(the row with most non-zero values) and remove all other rows...please suggest a solution.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the below code should work. The idea is to sort the matrix first according to the number of elements in the rows, then loop and remove the rows that have matches. Probably not the most efficient code but should work in principle.. see the comments for more explanation

```
% generating the data
M = zeros(6, 10);
M(2,1:3) = [3 8 10];
M(3,1:4) = [3 8 10 9];
M(4,1:5) = [3 8 10 9 7];
M(5,1:6) = [3 8 10 9 7 4];
M(6,1) = [5];

% sorting according to the number of non-zero elements
nr_of_nonzero = sum(M~=0, 2);
[~, sort_indices] = sort(nr_of_nonzero);
M_sorted = M(sort_indices,:);
M_sorted(M_sorted==0)=NaN; % should not compare 0s (?)

% get rid of the matches
for i=1:size(M_sorted, 1)-1
    for j=(i+1):size(M_sorted, 1)
        [C,ia,ib] = intersect(M_sorted(i,:),M_sorted(j,:));
        if numel(C)>0
            M_sorted(i,:) = NaN;
        end
        break;
    end
end

% reorder
M(sort_indices,:) = M_sorted;

% remove all NaN rows
M(all(isnan(M),2),:) = [];
% back to 0s
M(isnan(M)) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not doing all the code here, but here's the steps that I would take to solve it. You will likely have to try different ways of doing it to obtain the intended result (i.e. vector operations, while loop, for loop, etc.).

**Problem**

Rows are repetitive and need to be reduced in a more compact form.

**Solution**

1. Look up [`mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html).
2. Convert your vectors (rows) to strings. This can be done with temporary values like `tmpstr1 = mat2str(yourMatrix(rowToBeCompared, :));`
3. Parse the first string from beginning to end, while parsing the second string in the same way to make comparisons.
4. use `strcmp` to see if the string characters (or strings themselves) are the same: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html
5. Delete a row if you find it appropriate with `yourMatrix[rowToDelete, : ] = [];`

Try that and see if it works.

**Note - Expansion of step 3:**

if we have variable `a = '[ab+11]';`, we can select individual characters from the string like:

```
 a(4)
ans = '+'
a(5)
ans = '1'
a(1)
and = '['
```

Therefore, you can parse the string with a loop:

```
for n = 1 : length(a)
    if a(n) == '1' || a(n) == '0'
        str(n) = a(n);
    end
end
```

Like Sardar Usama said, it's helpful to provide the code so that we can copy and paste into our own MATLAB workspaces.